# Docker: Building within corporate firewall, deploying outside?

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a software suite (node web server, database, other tools) that I'm developing inside a corporate firewall, building into docker images, and deploying with docker-compose. In order to actually install all the software into the images, I need to set up the environment to use a network proxy, and also to disable strict SSL checking (because the firewall includes ssl inspection), not only in terms of environment variables but also for `npm`, `apt` and so on.

I've got all this working so that I can build within the firewall and deploy within the firewall, and have set up my Dockerfiles and build scripts so that enabling all the proxy/ssl config stuff is dependent on a docker `--build-arg` which sets an environment variable via `ENV enable_proxies=$my_build_arg`, so I can also just as easily skip all that configuration for building and deploying outside the firewall.

However, I need to be able to build everything inside the firewall, and deploy outside it. Which means that all the proxy stuff has to be enabled at build time (so the software packages can all be installed) if the relevant `--build-arg` is specified, and then also separately either enabled or disabled at runtime using `--env enable_proxies=true` or something similar.

I'm still relatively new to some aspects of Docker, but my understanding is that the only thing executed when the image is run is the contents of the `CMD` entry in the Dockerfile, and that `CMD` can only execute a single command.

Does anyone have any idea how I can/should go about separating the proxy/ssl settings during build and runtime like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to build and ship a single image; “build inside the firewall, deploy outside” is pretty normal.

One approach that can work for this is to use Docker’s multi-stage build functionality to have two stages.  The first maybe has special proxy settings and gets the dependencies; the second is the actual runtime image.

```
FROM ... AS build
ARG my_build_arg
ENV enable_proxies=$my_build_arg
WORKDIR /artifacts
RUN curl http://internal.source.example.com/...

FROM ...
COPY --from=build /artifacts/ /artifacts/
...
CMD ["the_app"]
```

Since the second stage doesn’t have an `ENV` directive, it never will have `$enable_proxies` set, which is what you want for the actual runtime image.

Another similar approach is to write a script that runs on the host that downloads dependencies into a local build tree and then runs `docker build`.  (This might be required if you need to support particularly old Dockers.)  Then you could use whatever the host has set for `$http_proxy` and not worry about handling the proxy vs. non-proxy case specially.

Comment: The multi-stage build sounds ideal, and pretty straightforward. Didn't know about that feature at all!